# Neck pain and handlebar adjustment

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars, adjustment, pain

I have a medium size [Scott Scale 40 (2009)](https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?item=17527) and my height is 1.73m.

Whenever I ride this bike I feel that something about my posture is wrong, back and neck pains are killing me after 1 hour.

I think that the handlebar is lower than it should be. It looks like I'm getting a low position and my head is looking more to downwards.

I want to try to raise the handlebar but I have no clue what extra parts I need to purchase first. I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: What are your cycling stats, frequency, time & distance (per ride and overall)? It could be a problem upper body strength.

Comment: I don't have much strength this year, but i had the same problem in the past when i was cycling a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This bike has a threadless stem. Based on the picture, it seems the handlebar is already at the highest possible position with stock parts (spacers below stem, stem flipped up), and there is little adjustment in the form of spacers.

There are two possibilities for your discomfort. Either the handlebar is too far from the saddle, or the handlebar is too low. Most likely both.

In order to help your situation, buy a threadless stem with a high 35 degree angle. The spec doesn't specify the handlebar mount diameter, but I suspect a 1+1/8" steerer tube attachment, 31.8mm handlebar attachment stem is what you need.

Looking at the picture, the existing stem seems to be 6 degrees, perhaps around 90mm? The specs don't say this.

The 35 degree stems can be found as short as 60mm. Such a 60mm 35 degree stem moves the handlebar 46mm closer to you when compared to 90mm 6deg stem. It also moves the handlebar 12mm up. So much closer but not much more up.

By buying a 35 degree 80mm stem, you can move the handlebar 28mm up and 34mm closer to you, when compared to 90mm 6deg stem.

So, I suspect a 35 degree 80mm stem is what you need.

Of course, before knowing what fit is ideal, you might find a 80mm stem with adjustable angle a good starting point.

However, before adjusting the handlebar position, adjust your saddle height and move your saddle forwards/backwards as desired. A good starting point is *knee over pedal spindle*, but it's just a starting point. So, sit on the bike, with one leg forwards and one backwards on the pedal, have a thread with weight hanging from the front of your front knee. It should show a vertical line that is directly over the pedal spindle. This is the forwards/backwards adjustment. Before it, you need to get your saddle height correct. The easiest way is to gradually increase the saddle height. You know when it's too high.

The reason for adjusting first your saddle position is that any saddle adjustments will nullify any handlebar adjustments you can make. Seat adjustments are often free, i.e. the seat can be moved forwards/backwards/up/down with the stock seatpost. However, moving handlebar closer and higher will require buying a new stem.

Comment: Moving the handlebar closer to the steerer is likely to make the handling of the bike more 'nervous'.

Comment: @Carel I disagree. I used to have a cheap bike where the handlebar ends were curved towards the rider. Equivalent to a straight handlebar and short stem. The cheap curved handlebar bike had the least 'nervous' handling of any bike I have ever owned. Or I'm not sure if my definition of 'nervous' is the same as your definition...

Comment: Let me guess: that bike also had wide tires and shallow steering angle combined with high rake fork. These things together make the bike stable at low speeds.

Comment: @juhist: The position of the bar-ends and the length of the stem don't cancel each other. The bar-ends of race-bars end far behind the steerer. Gripping the bars at the ends doesn't make the handling twitchy.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. May i ask if this stem would fit? https://www.bike24.com/p2166411.html

Comment: or this https://www.bike24.com/p2373662.html?menu=1000,2,114

Comment: @pror21 About the BBB, it gets your handlebars really high but I have no experience with such strange-looking stems. It might require you to do some changes to the headset preload bolt system. The ergotec, it won't move the handlebars as much up but I suspect it's enough if the 40deg side is up. To be sure, measure the handlebar mount with vernier calipers. It should be 31.8mm for the stem to fit. To install it, you need some resource on how to adjust headset tension -- if you don't get it right, the bearings fail in no time. You can of course pay a bike shop to install it.

Comment: Oh, and as I already stated, I suspect the 80mm adjustable stem is best but if you only want the handlebars up and not closer to the saddle, 100mm might be better. I think in most cases when you raise the handlebars, you should move it closer to the saddle as well.

Comment: Those stems are OK if you want to find out which angle fits you best but they have two disadvantages, the first one being greater weight and the second and major one is the fact that they introduce this joint that can come loose and wobbly with the surfaces getting worn. The bolt needs frequent checks for tightness as it is quite safety relevant.

Comment: Would be better to try these 2 stems? I think shorter length could be the key, as i need to bent a lot to reach the handles, and when i do all the weight is on my hands.

https://www.bike24.com/p27417.html (40mm)

https://www.bike24.com/p292056.html (50mm)